# Oracle Business intelligence - multiple standalone BI on single machine

Tags: oracle11g, business-intelligence, multiple-instances

Im going to install new Oracle BI enterprise edition along existing Oracle BI source edition. Is there any way i can install it on single machine?Can i use same BIPLATFORM schemas?

There isnt much to read about on oracle webpages. I see i can use software only to install binaries or install new oracle BI. But my question is. From tutorial I can see there is something like : *Ensure you install New oracle Business intelligence to separate middleware home*.

My middleware home is **.../fmw/** where Oracle BI is but also weblogic and others. So should i install new instance of weblogic too, or just install it under **../fmw/** to new folder named f.e. : **.../fmw/Oracle_BI2/**

Im quite confused. Im working for the first time with business intelligence from oracle.

IF someone experienced can give me a hint it would be much appreciated.

MATT.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install multiple BI systems in the same machine. Install WebLogic, then Software Only install and then run Configuration Wizard twice. Choose the Auto-port selection both the time.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e10539/c2_scenarios.htm#CHDDIDGE

Vijay